# Style elements in HTML in Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

May be it is a common way of working of libraries but i dont understand why i have so many style elements in my index.html where i use angular material. Here you see my header element that contains different classes for angular material components.

[image]

Is that working correctly? Is it slow downing my html file?

Comment: Read the "under the hood" section of theming docs for explanation

Comment: @charlietfl You posted your suggestion 4 minutes after I posted my answer, and they are basically suggesting the same thing. May I ask why? I'm looking up to users with such a vast experience as yours and try to learn the SO *unwritten ways* from them. Do you consider the question should have remained unanswered, since the OP clearly did not put up a proper documenting effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's [normal](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/05_under_the_hood).

> Each registered theme results in 16 `<style>` tags being generated.

And it's not slowing down your website. As a matter of fact, from all forms of adding CSS to a page, `<style>` is fastest.